# Controller/Directive inheritance in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble understanding how can I inherit a parent controller from a directive. I have setup a very simple example including a controller called `MainCrtl`. This controller is responsible of creating and removing an array of directives called `inner`. The thing is, I want to be able to access the methods of `MainCtrl` from my directives but I'm getting an error from the browser console. Here is the code:

app.js

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      });
  });
```

scripts/controllers/main.js

```js
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function () {
    var self = this;
    var index = 1;
    this.inners = [];
    this.init = function() {
      self.addInner();
    };
    this.addInner = function(){
      self.inners.push({
        name: 'Inner ' + index
      });
      index++;
    };
    this.init();
  });
```

views/main.html

```html
<p>main</p>
<button type="button" ng-click="main.addInner()">Add Inner</button>
<inner ng-repeat="inner in main.inners" data="inner"></inner>
```

scripts/directives/inner.js

```js
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('inner', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'inner.html',
      require: ['^MainCtrl', 'inner'],
      controllerAs: 'inner',
      bindToController: true,
      scope: {
        data: '='
      },
      controller: function(){ ... },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls){ ... }
    }
  });
```

And this is the error I'm getting from the browser console

```
[$compile:ctreq] Controller 'MainCtrl', required by directive 'inner', can't be found!
```

I have created a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4GjdazxVT4iZCLEvBRIG?p=preview). Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a directive can't have the kind of parent controllers that you're thinking of, a directive actually has parent directives. And each directive can have a controller if you specify it.

A directive is a parent of another if that is the case in the html.

```
<div parent-directive>
    <div child-directive></div>
</div>
```

In the parent directive's controller you need to define whatever you want to access on `this`.

Then 
`require: 'parent-directive'`
And
`link: function (scope, element, attrs, parent)`

Setting `require` to an array will result in an array being passed into the linking function. Optional controllers may be null.

Note you can also reference sibling directives as well. But you can't reference yourself (the same instance, that is).

Comment: umm that's what I was afraid of, it seems that I should create a new directive just to share the functionality. But I must say I disagree with your last sentence, a directive can actually reference itself in the require property . I know is unrelated but, how could you reference a sibling directive's controller?

Comment: To clarify, a directive instance can't reference itself. But two directive instances of the same type can.

Comment: You can reference a sibling using require as well. Prepend '^' to reference a parent or sibling, leave it out for siblings only. '?' Will make it optional. I think '^^' is parents only but it's not documented.. Can't remember if they added it.